# THT power transistor clamp mounting

Tags: mosfet, high-current, heatsink, igbt, busbar

I have a question regarding mounting THT power transistors (TO220, TO247...). I am building a output full bridge for a welder and I thought about *not* using PCB at all for the power terminals (D,S). It's pretty normal to use the tab of a transistor as a contact that is clamped to the heatsink whick function as a "high current" conductor. The tab is usually the drain..but what about the source? I am thinking about clamping the mosfet legs between a busbar and a clamping "washer".

I don't see any problem with that but I haven't seen it done anywhere so I thought about asking what you think.

Comment: TO-220 legs are not designed to be clamped like that and any pressure out-of-plane could crack the case.  Furthermore, they are relatively close together and all in the same plane.  How much current are we talking about here?

Comment: A soldered joint is best. Clamping or bolting could be used (note, not on TO-247, there's no tab, only a back side) but more importantly, what are you going to do about the supporting components (capacitors etc.)? Loop inductance can be quite a lot lower in a planar (PCB) design.

Comment: SOT-227B case is made for such mount situations.

Comment: You are indeed correct.
I know it is a weird application and there are much better packages to use so don't crucify me please. 
Technicaly I can snip off the drain pin (since drain is connected to the tab) and I would bend the gate pin upwards to interface with PCB containing the drivers. Then I am left with only a source pin.
I think I can take care of the out-of-plane clamping issue so cracking shouldn't be a much of a problem.
We are talking about paralleling multiple fets to get to about 2-300A?
In my mind the clamp could be "better" than soldering because of the surface contact area.

Comment: For 300A there are devices in packages with screw terminals and are designed to be bolted to a heatsink. Paralleling transistors for 300A might be challenging in regards to ensuring each device stays within it’s SOA.

Comment: @Kartman..yeah I know those packages pretty well but I was just wondering about this since I saw it in Marco Reps' video where he was servicing older tig welder with output full bridge that was made with something like 60 TO220 mosfets paralleled